# Knockout JS: Binding Dynamic Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, knockout.js, observable

I'm having some trouble in binding dynamically created dom elements

Code:

```
var i=0;

$.each(data.info, function(index, element) {                        
    $("#div1").append("<tr><td>" + element.Name + "</td><td>"+ element.Major +"</td><td>" + element.Sex +"</td><td>" + "<input data-bind='value: eng"+i+"' ></td><td>" + "<input data-bind='value: jap"+i+"' ></td><td>" +  "<input data-bind='value: cal"+i+"' ></td><td>" + "<input data-bind='value: geo"+i+"' ></td><td>" + "<strong data-bind='text: total'></td>" )
i++;
});
```

This creates row with input data-bind values eng0, eng1, jap0, jap1, etc.

I want to bind these as observables

Code

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.eng = ko.observable(element.English);
    this.jap = ko.observable(element.Japanese);
    this.cal = ko.observable(element.Calculus);
    this.geo = ko.observable(element.Geometry);

    this.total = ko.computed(function() {
    var tot=parseFloat(this.eng()) + parseFloat(this.jap()) + parseFloat(this.cal()) + parseFloat(this.geo());
    return (tot);    
    }, this);

}

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

This code is also inside `$.each(data.info, function(index, element){}`

I want some thing like

```
Var i=0;
$.each(data.info, function(index, element) {

function AppViewModel() {
        this.eng+i = ko.observable(element.English);
        this.jap+i = ko.observable(element.Japanese);
        this.cal+i = ko.observable(element.Calculus);
        this.geo+i = ko.observable(element.Geometry);

        this.total+i = ko.computed(function() {
        var tot=parseFloat(this.eng()) + parseFloat(this.jap()) + parseFloat(this.cal()) + parseFloat(this.geo());
        return (tot);    
        }, this);

    }
i++;
}
```

That get me result `this.eng0 = ko.observable()`

Note: the data is obtained from a JSON object. I have only included the iteration path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I suggest that using a [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) may be better than using jQuery's `each` and generating the HTML yourself? I'd suggest changing your view model to something like this:

```
function AppViewModel() {
   this.items = ko.observableArray();
}

function ItemViewModel(element) {
    this.eng = ko.observable(element.English);
    this.jap = ko.observable(element.Japanese);
    this.cal = ko.observable(element.Calculus);
    this.geo = ko.observable(element.Geometry);

    this.name = ko.observable(element.name);
    this.major = ko.observable(element.major);
    this.sex = ko.observable(element.sex);

    this.total = ko.computed(function () {
        var tot = parseFloat(this.eng()) + parseFloat(this.jap()) + parseFloat(this.cal()) + parseFloat(this.geo());
        return (tot);
    }, this);

};
```

Here, the AppViewModel is a container for the list of elements, and each element is its own ItemViewModel, with the properties you seem to have.

The html to bind this would be something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: major"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: sex"></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: eng' /></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: jap' /></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: cal' /></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: geo' /></td>
        <td><strong data-bind='text: total' /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When you get the JSON from your server you can use Knockout's [built-in JSON stuff](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html), the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), or parse them yourself. I created an example using the latter option in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNaUg/1/).

Comment: Thanx. I would like to know is there any way so that i can bind observables to dynamic elements, just like eng+1.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "eng+1" or "dynamic elements"? Perhaps you should try out what you want, and ask a follow-up question SO if you get stuck.